# npm nested dependency not latest version

Tags: node.js, npm, semantic-versioning, npm-shrinkwrap

In my Node.js project, I have a dependency `gulp` which has a dependency `vinyl-fs` which has a dependency `glob-watcher` which has a dependency `gaze`. `glob-watcher` is version `0.0.6` has its `gaze` dependency set to `^0.5.1`.

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343224/difference-between-tilde-and-caret-in-package-json) the `^` (caret) means that the latest minor version is accepted. So I expect `glob-watcher` to install the latest minor version of `gaze`, which (at the time of this writing) is `0.6.4`. But it doesn't, only `0.5.1` is installed.

Question: Why? How do I fix this?

I have tried adding the following `npm-shrinkwrap.json` to my project root and running `rm -rf node_modules/ && npm install`:

```
{
  "name": "MyProject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "gulp": {
      "version": "3.8.11",
      "from": "gulp@~3.8.10",
      "dependencies": {
        "vinyl-fs": {
          "version": "0.3.13",
          "from": "vinyl-fs@^0.3.0",
          "dependencies": {
            "glob-watcher": {
              "version": "0.0.6",
              "from": "glob-watcher@^0.0.6",
              "dependencies": {
                "gaze": {
                  "version": "0.6.4",
                  "from": "gaze@^0.5.1"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

That did make it so the version of `gaze` that I wanted was installed, but unfortunately that configuration results in ONLY those 4 dependencies being installed. I could specify my entire dependency tree to fix that, but that would be undesirable, especially because I'd just like to override that one package. (But it doesn't seem like overriding should even be necessary, according to the purported behavior of `^`.)

Obviously I could also write a shell script to `cd` to that dependency and manually `npm install` the version I want, but I'd rather do this the "right" way, if there is one.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What version of NPM are you using?

Comment: `npm --version 1.4.28`

Answer (score 0):

> Why?

Pretty simple: the latest version of *gaze* has just not been `npm publish`ed yet, and is still on version 0.5.1 on the [npm repo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gaze)

> How do I fix this?

You kinda scr***. The solution would be to use a `npm install [githubtarball] --save` but you don't want to manually edit the *package.json* of a dependency, and you ton want to fork *glob-watcher*, *vinyl-fs* and *gulp*.

**Edit:** maybe using this url *https://github.com/shama/gaze/tarball/v0.6.4* in shrinkwrap would work.